# Router dropping connections

Tags: wireless-networking, router

my router keeps dropping connection when more than 10-15 devices are connected..this is a big problem as I would regularly have that many and more devices connected.

I currently use a 3347WG router which operates fine with up to 10 devices connected.

A friend has suggested Powerline Adapters as a possible solution to my problem, which would be great, but do they not just extend/amplify the signal?  Will this be of any benefit as the problem only occurs with large   numbers of users/devices?

Comment: First I can see absolutely no reason that powerline adapters would help anything at all. they just replace cable. do you believe you have a cabling issue? Are any of your clients running bittorrent clients, or other protocols that create potentially hundreds of small connections? Does rebooting the router solve the problem temporarilly? Also, I'm seeing your router online for 30USD. I would not expect a device in that price range to work reliably for scalable requirements.

Comment: When the router is dropping connections, Are you referring to wireless connections only, or both wired and wireless?
Also, as @FrankThomas said, powerline adapters will let you use your electrical wiring to connect to the network.   It is mostly used as a substitute when you cannot run RJ45 cable to the location you need it.

Comment: How many IP addresses can this router provide as configured?  Some routers have a low default range.  Also possible as @ Frank Thomas notes,that the hardware cannot handle the traffic created by the connected devices.  You may need to add a second access point or offload traffic to a wired connection(s)

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, really helpful. I've been in touch with my provider & they say it's probably a hardware issue & are sending me out an upgraded router, hopefully that will take care of the problem. Also just in answer to pooter03 it was dropping both wired & wireless connections.